# How to use 'expect' in playwright with C# - Xunit

Tags: c#, playwright

Im porting some playwright tests over from visual studio code in js, to visual studio C# using xuint.

I cant seem to get the expect command to work in visual studio.

in the javascript project i would do the following to check an element contains some text:

```
await expect(page.locator('elementtofind')).toContainText('myText');
```

In C# if i write the same thing i get
'The name 'identifier' does not exist in the current context' error on the expect command

In the JS project my import statement is

```
import { test, expect } from '@playwright/test';
```

In the C# project im using:

```
using Microsoft.Playwright;
```

which does not appear to contain the expect

As a temporary workaround im doing the following in C# to achieve the same result

```
var item1 = page.Locator("elementtofind");
        Assert.Equal("myText", await item1.InnerTextAsync());
```

but would like to make use of the expect functionality in my tests.

Does anyone know how I can make this work in my project?

Comment: `expect` isn't coming from playwright, rather it's a function from the JS testing environment (namely Jest?), so there is no `expect` exactly in C#, your "workaround" isn't that, it's the C# counterpart. Well, not the exact counterpart, as `toContainText` actually "translates" to `Assert.IsTrue(await item1.InnerTextAsync().Contains("myText"))`

Comment: Thanks for you comment, Im new to both approaches (Also playwright), comparing both to other frameworks to see which ones are most suitable for our team

Comment: I just remembered that I thought I saw the expect used somewhere in a .Net example.... its on the playwright documentation page https://playwright.dev/dotnet/docs/writing-tests unfortunately it looks like this is only  supported for MS test and NUnit as it appears to be part of the Nuget packages for both. There is no Xuint  specific Nuget package for playwright which is maybe why i cant use it

Comment: https://fluentassertions.com/introduction

Answer (score 12):

If you're using xUnit, unfortunately, you can't use Expect directly. For NUnit and MSTest there's a base class `PageTest` that you can derive your tests from that provide this method. A future version of xUnit might make it possible to create a similar base class, but for now I haven't seen a good way to do the equivalent.

As a work around in xUnit, I use the Playwright `Assertions` class directly in my tests, for example:

```
await Assertions.Expect(Page.Locator("h1")).ToHaveTextAsync("Foo");
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. In the short time ive been comparing the two (X and N unit for playwright) I've found that playwright support for xunit, although supported is somewhat limited. Im putting together a list of pros and cons for each to help decide which frame work we decide to use. Have you found that there are any big drawbacks to using Xunit over Nuint other than having to implement work arounds such as the one mentioned here?

Comment: Sorry for the delayed reply @bobe_b. The lack of a base class for tests hasn't been a big drawback in using Playwright with xUnit for me. You should also be aware of the issues in xUnit that impact running tests in parallel (see https://playwright.dev/dotnet/docs/test-runners#xunit-support)

Comment: To further simplify this you could do a static import: `using static Microsoft.Playwright.Assertions;` which allows you to invoke `Expect()` without the `Assertions.` prefix.
Some advantages (for now!) to use NUnit over XUnit in e2e testing is the native support for adding attachments (for example to use in Azure pipelines) and the parallel running of tests